# How to get out of an event handler from a alert dialog?

Tags: java, android

So there is an alert dialog that checks if a value exist in the preferences and I can't get out of the main onClickListener from the negative button.

```
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        EditText et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);

        String code = et.getText().toString();
        String name = et2.getText().toString();
        if (prefs.contains(code)) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Definitions.this);
            builder.setTitle(R.string.error);
            builder.setCancelable(false);
            builder.setMessage(R.string.value_exist);
            builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.positive, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.negative, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    //how to get out of the main onClickListener from here?
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }
        editor.putString(code, name);
        editor.apply();
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you rephrase your question more precisely? Execution of `onClick()` on your `View` doesn't stop because you're opening a `Dialog`, so there is nothing to "get out off" when your `Dialog` closes.

Comment: I don't want to execute two last lines if the user clicks NO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The onClick method here :

```
builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.negative, new  DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //how to get out of the main onClickListener from here?
            }
        });
```

is not executed during your *main listener execution*, but only when you click on the negative button.

The last 2 lines :

```
    editor.putString(code, name);
    editor.apply();
```

are already executed when your alert become visible.

What you can probably do to fix your problem is this :

```
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ...
        if (prefs.contains(code)) {
            ...
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }else{
            editor.putString(code, name);
            editor.apply();
        }
    }
});
```